# Align lists vertically under multiple headers

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

I am working angular and i have to create this: [image: UI].

So far i was able to just create the 'headers' in same 'row' but now i need to show a list under each `header`. I will be getting `data` to show under `Reattempt`, `Returned` and `Delivered`. But i do not know how can i align the list under each `header`.

I will have three different `arrays` in three different variables. So how can i show list under each header? Also i am not well versed with frontend development since its not my area of expertise.

Here is what i am doing to show `headers` in a `row`

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
    <div *ngFor = "let item of statuses">
        <h1>{{item.header}}</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

I don't know what i need to do next. Your help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would add list items to your statuses array:

```
statuses[0].list = reattemptList;
statuses[1].list = returnedList;
// etc.
```

```
<div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="space-evenly center">
    <div *ngFor = "let item of statuses">
        <h1>{{item.header}}</h1>
        <div class="list-items">
          <div *ngFor = "let listItem of item.list">
             // Here you do something with your list items
             // {{listItem.name}}
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: that's good solution but what if i cannot/do not want to add list items to statuses array? For more clarity, actually i'll also be implementing a functionality that when a certain status will changes of any list item in returned/ reattemp they will be moved to warehouse or returned at. So are you sure that adding items to statuses array will be a good way forward?

Comment: Sure, just move/add items from `statuses[x].list` arrays or the original arrays themselves, since they will both reference the same object.

Comment: Awesome, but you my friend just took my night's sleep since i was hoping that i will be getting answer by morning. Now i am pumped to finish this task since there is a lot of coding involved here for other functionalities

Comment: Haha, do take your rest too!